# Подготовка файла для импорта в Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: java, форматирование, mathematica

Я записываю в *.txt*-файл определённое значение, содержащее время, в которое оно было получено. Вот код (код некрасивый — это только попытки решения необходимой задачи):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(txtText);
int start = 0;
int []rez = {0,0,0,0};
while (matcher.find(start)) {
   String value = txtText.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
   int result = Integer.parseInt(value);
   rez[start] = result; 
   start = matcher.end();
}

if(rez[3]-100 < 0){
    rez[0] = rez[0] * 10;
    if(rez[3]-10 < 0){
        rez[0] = rez[0] * 10;
    }
}

System.out.println(rez[0]+" "+rez[3]);

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();

FileWriter writeFile = null;
try {
    writeFile = new FileWriter(txtFile,true);
    writeFile.append(dateFormat.format(date)+"\t");
    int foo = Integer.parseInt(rez[0]+""+rez[3]);
    writeFile.append(foo+"\n");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(writeFile != null) {
        try {
            writeFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Записанный файл выглядит так:

[image: текстовый файл]

Но при последующем импорте все данные идут одним куском, т.е. я не могу получить определенную строку, или определенную ячейку (пересечение строки и столбца). Я так понимаю, что дело в записи данных в файл. Как можно записать данные в файл так, чтобы потом их можно было вновь разделить?

**UPD:**

Всё дело в том, что импортировать я пытаюсь в **Wolfram Mathematica**. Я попытался записывать не в *.txt,* а в *.xls* (**Wolfram Mathematica** его нормально импортирует) используя **Apache POI**, но у меня не получилось записывать в *.xls*-файл динамически получаемые данные: я использую метод `write()`, а метода `append()` в библиотеке **Apache POI** нет. Попробую разобраться с **CSV** — скорее всего, это то, что мне нужно (я и так использую **TSV**).

**UPD2:**

Вариант с **CSV** не подходит: я ведь использую **TSV**, и импорт всё равно не удается.

Comment: _"При последующем импорте"_ куда?

Comment: Не важно. Куда бы не импортировать- все равно одним куском идет

Comment: Важно. То, куда вы импортируете, ожидает определённый формат.

Comment: Если вы нашли решение - оформите его ответом, а не отвечайте прямо в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от того, какой формат ожидает приложение, куда эти данные импортируются. Например, можно записывать данные в CSV формате.

Пример входных данных

```
Display Name   Age
Micheal 30
Bill 25
```

Между ячейками ставится запятая, для перехода на следующую строку `\n`

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);

    writer.append("DisplayName");
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append("Age");
    writer.append('\n');

    writer.append("Micheal");
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append("30");
    writer.append('\n');

    writer.append("Bill");
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append("25");
    writer.append('\n');

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

Этот файл уже можно импортировать в Excel, будет нормальная таблица.

Comment: Угу, а обрабатывать запятые в строках кто будет? И символы перевода строки в них же? Пишете незнакомый формат — пишите не руками, а специализированной библиотекой.

Comment: Примета: писать руками CSV - к дебагу.

Comment: Это был элементарный пример. Автор пишет данные в определенном формате, запятых у него нет. Делаешь замечания-загляни сперва сам. При импорте в екселе есть возможность указать, какие символы являются разделителями.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что импортируете вы в свое же приложение и можете выбирать структуру данных в файле, иначе у вас нет особых вариантов и вам необходимо делать файл в формате, который понимает импортирующая программа.

Для самостоятельного решения импорта данных между вашими приложениями, вам нужно использовать не просто запись в одну "кучу" в текстовый файл, а использовать какой то язык структурирования данных, имеющих готовые парсеры и врайтеры в Java, который можно записать и потом распарсить для получения отдельных записей, используя либо собственные библиотеки Java, либо возможно и внешние, хотя в случае такой простой структуры, как в вашем случае, они не очень понадобятся: JSON, XML, CSV и тп.

Можно, конечно, написать свой парсер и для такой структуры, как у вас сейчас (или использовать псевдо-CSV формат - добавлять разделители и маркеры понятные вашему парсеру) , но это будет не очень логичное решение, так как существуют уже готовые отлаженные и документированные решения.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так: Записывал в файл в том виде, в котором мне потом было бы проще работать с этими данными в Wolfram Mathematika. Вот пример:

> {2015,08,06,04,13,43,445280},{2015,08,06,04,13,53,445280},{2015,08,06,04,14,04,445280},

**UPD**
Вопрос решен) Wolfram понимает и CSV и TSV просто ему нужно было специальной функцией показывать, что это CSV или TSV. Там еще куча всяких форматов.

Comment: Если вы нашли решение - поделитесь им с сообществом, опишите его подробно. Какая специальная функция и тд. Это поможет другим решить аналогичную проблему.